# Normal Mapping on Texture Splatted Terrain

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl, webgl, shader

I have developed a terrain generation system with texture splatting in Three.js and I am having trouble applying normal mapping to it. How should I go about it? This code is fully functional as of now.

I have looked at some tutorials of WebGL shading and normal mapping and I could not find one to accurately fit my code.

```
FRAGMENT_SHADER: `
    uniform sampler2D albedoA;
    uniform sampler2D albedoB;
    uniform sampler2D albedoC;
    uniform sampler2D albedoD;
    uniform sampler2D albedoE;

    uniform sampler2D normalA;
    uniform sampler2D normalB;
    uniform sampler2D normalC;
    uniform sampler2D normalD;
    uniform sampler2D normalE;

    uniform float repeatScale;

    uniform vec3 sunPosition;

    varying vec2 vUV;
    varying float vAmount;

    varying vec3 vNormal;
    varying vec3 vWorldPosition;

    void main()
    {
        vec3 diffA = (smoothstep(0.01, 0.25, vAmount) - smoothstep(0.25, 0.35, vAmount)) * texture2D(albedoA, vUV * repeatScale).rgb;
        vec3 diffB = (smoothstep(0.24, 0.27, vAmount) - smoothstep(0.27, 0.37, vAmount)) * texture2D(albedoB, vUV * repeatScale).rgb;
        vec3 diffC = (smoothstep(0.28, 0.32, vAmount) - smoothstep(0.32, 0.42, vAmount)) * texture2D(albedoC, vUV * repeatScale).rgb;
        vec3 diffD = (smoothstep(0.30, 0.60, vAmount) - smoothstep(0.40, 0.70, vAmount)) * texture2D(albedoD, vUV * repeatScale).rgb;
        vec3 diffE = (smoothstep(0.50, 0.85, vAmount))                                   * texture2D(albedoE, vUV * repeatScale).rgb;
        vec3 albedoVector = diffA + diffB + diffC + diffD + diffE;

        vec3 normA = (smoothstep(0.01, 0.25, vAmount) - smoothstep(0.25, 0.35, vAmount)) * texture2D(normalA, vUV * repeatScale).rgb;
        vec3 normB = (smoothstep(0.24, 0.27, vAmount) - smoothstep(0.27, 0.37, vAmount)) * texture2D(normalB, vUV * repeatScale).rgb;
        vec3 normC = (smoothstep(0.28, 0.32, vAmount) - smoothstep(0.32, 0.42, vAmount)) * texture2D(normalC, vUV * repeatScale).rgb;
        vec3 normD = (smoothstep(0.30, 0.60, vAmount) - smoothstep(0.40, 0.70, vAmount)) * texture2D(normalD, vUV * repeatScale).rgb;
        vec3 normE = (smoothstep(0.50, 0.85, vAmount))                                   * texture2D(normalE, vUV * repeatScale).rgb;
        vec3 normalVector = normA + normB + normC + normD + normE;

        float diffuseFloat = max(dot(normalize(sunPosition - vWorldPosition), vNormal), 0.0);
        if (diffuseFloat < 0.25) { diffuseFloat = 0.25; }
        if (diffuseFloat > 1.0) { diffuseFloat = 1.0; }

        gl_FragColor = vec4(diffuseFloat * albedoVector, 1.0);
    }
`,
VERTEX_SHADER: `
    uniform sampler2D heightTexture;

    varying vec2 vUV;
    varying float vAmount;

    varying vec3 vNormal;
    varying vec3 vWorldPosition;

    void main()
    {
        vUV = uv;
        vAmount = texture2D(heightTexture, uv).r;

        vec4 worldPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);

        vWorldPosition = worldPosition.xyz;
        vNormal = vec3(normal);

        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * worldPosition;
    }
`
```

I am using the THREE.ShaderMaterial and as of now the code splats the textures and accounts for lighting and shadows, but not the normal maps.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the normal of a surface (terrain) by the simple numerical approximation - See [Finite difference method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_method).

You have to know the size of the height map texture. I recommend to set the size of the texture to a uniform variable:

```c
uniform sampler2D heightTexture;
uniform vec2 heightTextureSize;  // (width, height) of heightTexture;
```

Calculate the offset between adjacent texels of the texture:

```c
vec2 offset = 1.0 / heightTextureSize;
```

Read the height of the adjacent texels of the texture

```c
vA = texture2D(heightTexture, uv).r;

vAL = texture2D(heightTexture, uv + vec2(-offset.x,  0.0)).r;
vAR = texture2D(heightTexture, uv + vec2( offset.x,  0.0)).r;
vAB = texture2D(heightTexture, uv + vec2( 0.0, -offset.y)).r;
vAT = texture2D(heightTexture, uv + vec2( 0.0,  offset.y)).r;
```

Finally you can calculate the approximated normal vector in texture space

```c
vec3 normalMap = normalize( vec3(vAL - vAR, vAT - vAB, 2.0) );
```

Comment: Hi again, how would I implement the normal textures with the normal vector?

Comment: Would I add it to the vNormal value as such?    float diffuseFloat = max(dot(normalize(sunPosition - vWorldPosition), vNormal + (normalVector * normalMap)), 0.0);